# How can I reopen my psd file and view the layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, jpg

I saved my work as a jpg from photoshop but now i need to make edits to the file.  How can I view th layers again in photoshop? I need to add a complete da

[image: CWNC Event Banner]

Comment: You must have that PSD file to make any change.

Answer (score 4):

## You can't.

When you save to jpg you create a *flat file* without layers and no layer information is retained. You threw away all layers when you saved as a jpg. There is no way to get layers back.

If you want to retain layers in any file, you should save it to the native .psd format.

Comment: in fact you should allways save your files as PSD and after that in jpg just in case.

Comment: Additionally to what joojaa mentioned, you should always save multiple times while you create a layout. Things happen; power shortage, cat pulls the plug, meteor strike, etc. A .psd doesn't become a .jpg if the project was saved a few (at least one) times!